# Formatting locally the \hline command in a table

Tags: tables, macros

Is it possible to alter the `\hline` command in a table to mimic commands like `\dotfill`? I would like to be able to change the way the `\hline` command looks without loading another package like `arydshln`.

Comment: `\multispan{4}{\dotfill}\cr` if it is a 4 column table

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suppose this can be made into a command, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
\newcommand\zz[1]{\multispan{#1}{\dotfill}\cr}
```

Then in a 4 column table

```
a&b&c&d\\
\zz{4}
```

Comment: That implies hardcoding the number of columns *inside* the `tabular`, not just at the beginning. Is there no way of making your solution more maintainable?

Comment: @Jubobs not really, or at least not without redefining chunks of the tabular environment, but that leads to something like arydshln, which the OP wanted to avoid. Although in practoce the number of columns is hard coded all over the tabular anyway, every row has a fixed number of `&`, `\multicolumn` and `\cline` imply knowledge about column numbers etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where can I find a list of those commands specifically to tables like `\multispan{<>}{<>}` and `\noalign{<>}` and how to use them?

Comment: @azetina texbook (you are not supposed to use them in latex of course:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why?

Comment: @azetina in general tex primitives (`\noalign`) and plain tex commands (`\multispan`) are not guaranteed to interact well with higher level latex constructs such as `tabular`. Although in this case it's safe enough.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So what would be more safe? What other options are there in creating an appropriate command?

Comment: @azetina nothing. If latex doesn't provide a feature, it is sometimes necessary to implement it using TeX primitives.